# Laravel primary key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Como puedo cambiar por defecto la primary key en laravel?

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddSubcategorias extends Migration
{

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categorias', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->primary(array('acronimo_categorias', 3));
        $table->string('descripcion', 50);
        $table->string('registro_calidad' ,1);
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('categorias');
}
}
```

En la documentación de laravel pone que poniendo primary deberia de funciona tambien e probado de esta manera:

```
$table->primary('acronimo_categorias,', 3);
```

Pero tampoco le da por funcionar, uso laravel 5,2

Comment: Se lee un poco rara la sintaxis que utilizas, ¿podrías explicar qué tipo de campo o campos deseas utilizar como llave primaria?

Comment: Modifique el codigo y meti la primera tabla la de antes era la segunda y era raro no saber de donde viene el references

Comment: ¿qué tipo de campo es `acronimo_categorias`? texto, varchar, integer...

Comment: seria un CHAR de 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma correcta según la sintaxis de Laravel sería algo así, primero defines el campo y luego lo marcas como índice primario:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categorias', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->char('acronimo_categorias', 3);
        $table->string('descripcion', 50);
        $table->string('registro_calidad' ,1);

        $table->primary('acronimo_categorias');
    });
}
```